# Why is my cell event not triggered?

Tags: itext

Need help with iText cell event not firing.

In the demonstration below i am expecting the cell event to trigger twice. But it only triggers on the first cell. The difference appears to be that the cell event of the first cell
is added to the cell *before* adding the cell to the table. I've read the book and the javadoc and can't see that mentioned as a prerequisite. Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

```java
public class ITextCellEvent {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
        Document doc = new Document( PageSize.A4 );
        float twocm = Utilities.millimetersToPoints( 20f );
        doc.setMargins( twocm, twocm, twocm, twocm );
        PdfWriter.getInstance( doc, new FileOutputStream( new File( "iTextCellEventProblem.pdf" ) ) );
        try {
            doc.open();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable( 2 );
            table.setTotalWidth( doc.right() - doc.left() );
            table.setLockedWidth( true );
            table.setWidths( new int[] { 50, 50 } );

            PdfPCell leftCell = new PdfPCell();
            leftCell.addElement( new Paragraph( "I am the left" ) );
            leftCell.setCellEvent( new MyCellEvent() ); //Event added to cell before adding cell to table, it works.

            PdfPCell rightCell = new PdfPCell();
            rightCell.addElement( new Paragraph( "I am the right" ) );

            table.addCell( leftCell );
            table.addCell( rightCell );
            rightCell.setCellEvent( new MyCellEvent() );    //Event added to cell after adding cell to table, doesn't work.

            doc.add( table );
        }
        finally {
            doc.close();
        }
    }

    static final class MyCellEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {
        @Override
        public void cellLayout( PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases ) {
            System.out.println( "Cell event was called" );
        }
    }
}
```

The reason it matters is that i need to do some measurements of the table (and other things) and pass values into the constructor of the cell renderer. I can't take the table measurements until *after* i've added the cell to the table; which is why i need to
set the cell renderer after the cell has been added to the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cell` parameter of the `addCell()` method is final and changing `cell` after it has been added to the `PdfPTable` has no effect, because the object is being copied using the `PdfPCell` copy constructor of either the `PdfPHeaderCell` class or the `PdfPCell` class. We work on a copy because as soon as a cell is added to a table, we perform different operations on that cell. Should we do these operations on the original cell, then that cell can't be reused (and that is what some people do: they create a cell once and then reuse it).

There may be a workaround for your problem though. You could retrieve the copied cell from the row:

```
PdfPRow row = table.getRow(0);
PdfPCell cell = row.getCells()[1];
```

And then add the cell event to that `cell` instance. It's not elegant, but it might work.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, good explanation. And the work-around does work. cheers for that.